# I can't re-install the package "datasets" (default R datasets) I had deleted by mistake

Tags: r, dataset

I am learning to use R Studio, and I have deleted by mistake the default package "datasets", and now I can't re-install it.

"datasets" doesn't appear in the list of packages i can instal. also, if i try to code:

```
install.packages("datasets")
```

And I get the following error:

> Warning in install.packages :
>   package ‘datasets’ is not available (for R version 3.5.3)

```
sessionInfo()

R version 3.5.3 (2019-03-11)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Mojave 10.14.5
```

Note that so far I have imported the datasets one by one when needed, but now I need to run arulesViz, which doesn't work without the default "datasets" package.

```
library(arulesViz)
```

> Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘arulesViz’:
>
> package ‘datasets’ does not have a namespace

Comment: `datasets` is not installable via a repository, it comes as part of the base R installation. Not sure how you managed to delete it but you'll probably have to reinstall R to restore it.

Comment: thanks. would I have to reinstall R or R Studio?

Comment: It's part of R so start with that. If RStudio appears to have issues, reinstall that after R.

Comment: problem solved thanks to reinstalling R. thank you